# How to setup Bootstrap4 ToggleButtonGroup in Yii 2 with model?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

**When i use yii\bootstrap4\ToggleButtonGroup widget i get 2 major problems:**
1. The label is inline with buttons
2. error field doesn't appear

[image]

I've tried to access the label 'style' property but culdn't.
Also checked my model if my field has rule "required".

**Here is my view widget:**

```
<?php 
    echo $form->field($model, 'my_field', ['options' => []])->widget(\yii\bootstrap4\ToggleButtonGroup::class, [
    'type' => \yii\bootstrap4\ToggleButtonGroup::TYPE_RADIO,
        'items' => [
            '0' => 'No',
            '1' => 'Yes'
        ],
        'options' => [
            'class' =>'btn-group btn-group-toggle'
        ],
            'labelOptions' => [
            'class' => ['btn', 'btn-secondary'],
            'wrapInput' => false
        ]
    ]);
?>
```

I wish to have label uppon the ToggleButtonGroup (in new line) and i wish to see error field "this field is required" when none button is clicked and form is subbmitted.
[image]

**Thanks for help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you can disable the label by adding 'label'=>false  and manually add a

```
 <P> Yes or NO </p>

<?php 
    echo $form->field($model, 'my_field', ['options' => []])->widget(\yii\bootstrap4\ToggleButtonGroup::class, [
    'type' => \yii\bootstrap4\ToggleButtonGroup::TYPE_RADIO,
        'items' => [
            '0' => 'No',
            '1' => 'Yes'
        ],
        'options' => [
            'class' =>'btn-group btn-group-toggle'
        ],'label'=>false,
    ]);
?>
or ad
```

or add a custom class to the label

```
 'labelOptions' => [
            'class' => ['btn', 'btn-secondary Customclass'],
            'wrapInput' => false
        ]
```

and add a custom CSS class to your style

> .Customclass{ 
>     width:100%;
>        /*  Additional properties  */
>   }

Comment: Adding custom css class is just work arround.
Shure i can dissable the label but where can i set this property:
'label' => false ????

Comment: Try This <?php 
    echo $form->field($model, 'my_field', ['options' => []])->widget(\yii\bootstrap4\ToggleButtonGroup::class, [
    'type' => \yii\bootstrap4\ToggleButtonGroup::TYPE_RADIO,
        'items' => [
            '0' => 'No',
            '1' => 'Yes'
        ],
        'options' => [
            'class' =>'btn-group btn-group-toggle'
        ],'label'=>false,
    ]);
?>

Comment: It didnt work... got error: "Setting unknown property: yii\bootstrap4\ToggleButtonGroup::label"

Comment: this Answer is acceptable... thx

Answer (score 1):

The below code works fine.

**1. With Model**

```
<? echo $form->field($model, 'model_attribute')->widget(\yii\bootstrap\ToggleButtonGroup::classname(), [
    'type' => 'radio', //or 'checkbox'
    'items' => $model_attribute_options,
    'labelOptions' => [
        'class' => ['btn', 'btn-primary Customclass'],
        'wrapInput' => true
    ],
    'value' =>  [$model->model_attribute] //pass comma separated values for multi selection for checkbox type
]) ?>
```

**2. Without Model**

```
<?php 
echo ToggleButtonGroup::widget([
    'name' => 'sport',
    'type' => 'radio', //or 'checkbox'
    'items' => [
        0 => 'Soccer',
        1 => 'Basket',
        2 => 'Tennis',
    ],
    'value' =>  [0] //pass comma separated values for multi selection for checkbox type
 ]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the width percentage and margins (w-50 ml-3 mr-3) to adjust and force newline. Also using btn-outline-secondary pops out the chosen button.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'my_field', ['options' => ['class' => 'form-group'])->widget(\yii\bootstrap4\ToggleButtonGroup::class, [
'type' => \yii\bootstrap4\ToggleButtonGroup::TYPE_RADIO,
    'items' => [
        'Y' => 'Yes',
        'N' => 'No',
    ],
    'options' => [
        'class' =>'btn-group btn-group-toggle w-50 ml-3 mr-3',
    ],
        'labelOptions' => [
        'class' => ['btn', 'btn-outline-secondary'],
    ],
])->label('label here')->hint('hint here');
```

I did not have any issues with displaying error messages as well with the above.